# Dynamic data sharing Android/PC

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I want to develop a minimal app to send in real time the orientation (x and y axes) of my android phone to my computer, although I have no idea where to start. I would like to know how it is possible to share data dynamically between an android and a computer (Linux or windows)

Comment: Search 4 **multiplayer gps** @googleplay.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get this done, even if it is "ugly". I'm using MIT App Inventor to POST the orientation of the phone to a PHP server, which creates a json file, that I can get to my computer via a simple python script (since I need Python for the software I'm using).